# How to... 2 dimensional matrix using object as index?

Tags: c#, object, multidimensional-array, indexing

If have 2 classes, Teams and Games.
Something like this:

```
class Team {...}
class Games
{
    Team team1;
    Team team2;
    ...
}
```

And I have a List of all games played...

`List<Games> allGames ...`

What I now want to do is: for further statistics I need a matrix that counts how often each team played against every other team.

Earlier I would have solved this as follows:

```
int[,] countTeamVsTeam = new int[allTeams.Count, allTeams.Count];

foreach (Game game in allGames)
{
    countTeamVsTeam[game.team1.SOMENUMBER,game.team2.SOMENUMBER]++;
}
```

Now I wonder if it is a good idea to skip that artificial SOMENUMBER attribute and use the objects by themselves as an index of my data structure:

```
Dictionary<Team, Dictionary<Team, int>> countTeamVsTeam = new Dictionary<Team, Dictionary<Team, int>>();
// initialize 
foreach (Team team1 in allTeams)
{
    countTeamVsTeam[team1] = new Dictionary<Team, int>();
    foreach (string team2 in allTeams)
    {
        countTeamVsTeam[team1][team2] = 0;
    }
}

foreach (Game game in allGames)
{
    countTeamVsTeam[game.team1,game.team2]++;
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

Is this a good way of doing it?

Is that `Dictionary<Team, Dictionary<Team, int>>` a good data structure for representing the 2 dimensional matrix? (yes I know it's not an array but a dictionary of dictionaries...)

Comment: The problem I see with both of your methods is that it's fine if you look up `[team1][team2]`, but `[team2][team1]` it won't yield the same result.

Comment: That's fine (I distinguish home and away team)

Comment: I recommend using value tuples for the key of the Dictionary: `Dictionary<(Team,Team),int>`

Comment: Are teams interned? Is reference equality logically correct?

Comment: Yes. Teams are unique and exists for the lifetime of the program.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of options.

A Dictionary can actually have a tuple/composite key so you can define it as follows

```
Dictionary<(Team, Team), int> countTeamVsTeam = new Dictionary<(Team, Team), int>();
```

But as pointed out in the comments above, you need to strictly control the order of each team (home vs away, alphabetical, ordered by id etc.) as

`countTeamVsTeam[(team1, team2)]` will not have the same value as `countTeamVsTeam[(team2, team1)]`

Another option is to create a custom collection.  Within which you internally control the teams in a manner that is not visible externally so that you can abstract this detail and control the order of the teams so that you only store a single value no matter which order the teams are passed into the collection.

Comment: I like that  tuple/composite key thing a lot. Didn't know that this exists!
But why should the order of teams (alphabetical or by Id) be relevant? The object reference is key for the dictionary, so this should even work on items that are not sortable...

Comment: You need to have a rule/algorithm to define which is team1 and which is team2 which is consistent.  As explained above, if you swap the order you will get a different value!

Comment: That's not a problem, as it is well defined. game.team1 is team1 and game.team2 is team2 :-)